# AWS Lambda Function Triggers on S3 Event, But only Once in About 30 Mins

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have created a simple Lambda function to trigger upon creation of an object in S3 bucket, but it does not always trigger...

1. The function triggers and generates a log in CloudWatch when I upload a file to the bucket. However, when I upload the same or a different file about a minute later to the same bucket, the function does not trigger again.
2. If I re-save the function and upload a file to the bucket again, the function triggers again. If I upload the file again a minute or so later, the function does not trigger.
3. If I actually wait for about 30 mins (not just a min or two) and upload a file again, the function triggers without re-saving.

Below is the function code, Python 3.7. Why it does not trigger any time I upload a file to the bucket?

```
import json

print("This is a test")

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Setting variables to equal values from the event object passed in.
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    region = event['Records'][0]['awsRegion']
    object = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    user = event['Records'][0]['userIdentity']['principalId']

    print("Bucket: " + bucket)
    print("Region: " + region)
    print("User is " + user)

    return(object)
```

Thank you :)

Comment: @Nathan is right. also when you look for log messages in cloudwatch. remember that the log message `This is a test`  should log only once every 15 minutes. Because the lambda is in a warm state for 15 minutes. but other logs should print on every invocation.

Answer (score 3):

For non-versioned S3 objects, writes that occur at the same time may not create individual writes. AWS suggests turning on object versioning if you want to ensure that an event gets created for every write. This also means that a new version will be created with every write as well.

Documentation for said behavior can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is not an issue. Apparently, AWS bundles multiple lambda executions in the same Log Stream in the CloudWatch. So my Lambda function did execute each time I upload a file to the bucket, I just did not notice that the execution was logged in the same Log Stream and instead expected a new Log Stream created for each lambda execution.